# Create new instance uses much memory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, nevron

I use Nevron Chart in my program. following code is in a click button event:

```
this.nChartControl1 = new NChartControl();
// add data to chart ...
```

after each click program allocates a lot of memory and even `GC.Collect()` doesn't clean the memory, and if I use one instance of Nevron Chart and every time clean the data and then add new data every thing is OK.

what's the problem?

Update 1: here is the function

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (nChartControl1 == null)
        {
            this.nChartControl1 = new NChartControl();
        }

        // clear data
        nChartControl1.Charts.Clear();
        nChartControl1.Panels.Clear();
        GC.Collect();

        // empty the grid then add NevronChart
        this.grid.Children.Clear();
        this.grid.Children.Add(nChartControl1);

        nChartControl1.BackgroundStyle.FrameStyle.Visible = false;

        // set a chart title
        NLabel title = nChartControl1.Labels.AddHeader("2D Line Chart");

        // setup chart
        NCartesianChart chart = new NCartesianChart();
        nChartControl1.Panels.Add(chart);
        chart.DockMode = PanelDockMode.Fill;
        chart.Margins = new NMarginsL(2, 0, 2, 2);
        chart.Projection.SetPredefinedProjection(PredefinedProjection.Orthogonal);
        chart.LightModel.EnableLighting = false;
        chart.Axis(StandardAxis.Depth).Visible = false;
        chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Floor).Visible = false;
        chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Left).Visible = false;
        chart.BoundsMode = BoundsMode.Stretch;
        chart.Height = 40;
        chart.RangeSelections.Add(new NRangeSelection());
        chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX).ScrollBar.Visible = true;
        chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryY).ScrollBar.Visible = true;

        // setup the line series
        NLineSeries line = (NLineSeries)chart.Series.Add(SeriesType.Line);
        //line.Values.FillRandom(new Random(), 10);
        SetRandomData(line);

        line.DataLabelStyle.Visible = false;
        line.Legend.Mode = SeriesLegendMode.DataPoints;
        line.ShadowStyle.Type = ShadowType.GaussianBlur;
        line.ShadowStyle.Offset = new NPointL(new NLength(3, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel), new NLength(3, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel));
        line.ShadowStyle.FadeLength = new NLength(5, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        line.ShadowStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(55, 0, 0, 0);
        line.LineSegmentShape = LineSegmentShape.Line;


        nChartControl1.Controller.Tools.Add(new NSelectorTool());
        nChartControl1.Controller.Tools.Add(new NAxisScrollTool());
        nChartControl1.Controller.Tools.Add(new NDataZoomTool());
        NDataPanTool dpt = new NDataPanTool();
        nChartControl1.Controller.Tools.Add(dpt);
        nChartControl1.Legends.Clear();
        nChartControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: You should dispose the existing nChartControl1 before assigning a new instance to it

Comment: "every time clean the data", can you elaborate on what this means exactly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I updated with the entire function

Comment: @AlexK. I tried that but no effect!

Comment: How much memory is being allocated and how are you checking this?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway about 2 MB increases in Task Manager after each click.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the control using the following code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            using (NChartControl chartControl = new NChartControl())
            {
                // set a chart title
                NLabel title = chartControl.Labels.AddHeader("2D Line Chart");

                // setup chart
                NCartesianChart chart = new NCartesianChart();
                chartControl.Panels.Add(chart);
                chart.DockMode = PanelDockMode.Fill;
                chart.Margins = new NMarginsL(2, 0, 2, 2);
                chart.Projection.SetPredefinedProjection(PredefinedProjection.Orthogonal);
                chart.LightModel.EnableLighting = false;
                chart.Axis(StandardAxis.Depth).Visible = false;
                chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Floor).Visible = false;
                chart.Wall(ChartWallType.Left).Visible = false;
                chart.BoundsMode = BoundsMode.Stretch;
                chart.Height = 40;
                chart.RangeSelections.Add(new NRangeSelection());
                chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryX).ScrollBar.Visible = true;
                chart.Axis(StandardAxis.PrimaryY).ScrollBar.Visible = true;

                // setup the line series
                NLineSeries line = (NLineSeries)chart.Series.Add(SeriesType.Line);
                //line.Values.FillRandom(new Random(), 10);

                line.DataLabelStyle.Visible = false;
                line.Legend.Mode = SeriesLegendMode.DataPoints;
                line.ShadowStyle.Type = ShadowType.GaussianBlur;
                line.ShadowStyle.Offset = new NPointL(new NLength(3, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel), new NLength(3, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel));
                line.ShadowStyle.FadeLength = new NLength(5, NGraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                line.ShadowStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(55, 0, 0, 0);
                line.LineSegmentShape = LineSegmentShape.Line;


                chartControl.Controller.Tools.Add(new NSelectorTool());
                chartControl.Controller.Tools.Add(new NAxisScrollTool());
                chartControl.Controller.Tools.Add(new NDataZoomTool());
                NDataPanTool dpt = new NDataPanTool();
                chartControl.Controller.Tools.Add(dpt);
                chartControl.Legends.Clear();
                chartControl.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

And there was no memory leak in the control. So the answer is that you need to call dispose or use a using statement.